# xarray: Force the writing of string attribute as NC_CHAR (because of netcdf-fortran incompatibility with NC_STRING)

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

When I have a string attribute in my `xarray.Dataset` with special characters like ° or German Umlauts (Ä, Ü, etc) it will get written to file with `to_netcdf()` as type NC_STRING. Other string attributes not containing any special characters will be saved as NC_CHAR.

This leads to problems when I subsequently want to open this file with NetCDF-Fortran, because it does not fully support NC_STRING.

So my question is:
**Is there a way to force xarray to write the string attribute as NC_CHAR?**

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data = np.ones([12, 10])
ds = xr.Dataset({"data": (["x", "y"], data)}, coords={"x": np.arange(12), "y": np.arange(10)})
ds["x"].attrs["first_str"] = "foo"
ds["x"].attrs["second_str"] = "bar°"
ds["x"].attrs["third_str"] = "hää"
ds.to_netcdf("testds.nc")
```

The output of ncdump -h looks like this, which shows the different data type of the second and third attribute:

```
netcdf testds {
dimensions:
        x = 12 ;
        y = 10 ;
variables:
        double data(x, y) ;
                data :_FillValue = NaN ;
        int64 x(x) ;
                x:first_str = "foo" ;
                string x:second_str = "bar°" ;
                string x:third_str = "hää" ;
        int64 y(y) ;
}
```

For transparency: I already opened an issue at the xarray GitHub page, but have now wondered if it is better suited for stackoverflow. Here is the link: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7186

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an explanation and workaround, that was suggested at the GitHub issue:

> The reason for this behavior is that the netcdf4 python package
> automatically determines the type of the attribute (NC_CHAR or
> NC_STRING) by attempting the conversion to ASCII:
> Unidata/netcdf4-python#529 However, if the value is a byte string, no
> conversion is done. So, the easiest solution would be to manually
> encode as utf-8 and then passing the byte string to netcdf4.
> Unfortunately, xarray doesn't support byte strings as attribute values
> even though this is a valid data type for the netcdf4 engine.
>
> A quick workaround for you might be to encode the string as utf-8 and
> convert to a numpy array, since xarray accepts numpy arrays as data
> type and netcdf4 automatically extracts the data if the array contains
> only a single item:
>
> `ds["x"].attrs["third_str"] = np.array("hää".encode("utf-8"))`

See https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7186#issuecomment-1287864880